# How to utilize srcset in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

is there some best practice for using srcset in Ionic 4 PWAs / Apps ( with Angular )?

In webbrowsers it is a nice way, to provide multiple sources for responsive images, but the `<ion-img>` seems not to support it.

For angular itself I found the `ng-srcset` directive, which I could probably simply use on normal `img` elements.

This is what one would do in a website:

```html
<img src="https://host.de/path/img.jpg" srcset="
  https://host.de/path/img_760.jpg 760w, 
  https://host.de/path/img_380.jpg 380w, 
  https://host.de/path/img_752.jpg 752w,
  https://host.de/path/img_295.jpg 295w" 

  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 380px, (min-width: 992px) 376px, 39.2vw" 
  class="img-responsive">
```

Anybody knows if there is a specific "ionic way" of doing this?

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ion-img is mostly useful for lazy loading images (as under the hood it uses intersection observer). But in itself ion-img is a rather simple component, see the source:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/img/img.tsx

Since as you can see there this component does not leverage (yet?) srcset, you are free to leverage `<img>` itself in an Angular / Ionic as is (and I do not think there is anything wrong with it). You can do bindings etc:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" srcset='https://picsum.photos/300/300 300w, 
  https://picsum.photos/400/400 400w, 
  https://picsum.photos/600/600 600w,
  https://picsum.photos/600/600 400w'
  sizes="(min-width: 800px) 600px, (min-width: 600px) 400px, 39.2vw" 
  class="img-responsive"/>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" [srcset]='srcSetConfig'
  sizes="(min-width: 800px) 600px, (min-width: 600px) 400px, 39.2vw" 
  class="img-responsive"/>

</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.css'],
})
export class HomePage {

  srcSetConfig = `https://picsum.photos/300/300 300w, 
  https://picsum.photos/400/400 400w, 
  https://picsum.photos/600/600 600w,
  https://picsum.photos/600/600 400w`

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-bdpael